# Checking for the users input in a text file and if it is there it will print something

Tags: python

I am making a login/ sign up page in python for fun but im kinda stuck.
I have made my sign up page but im stuck with the login page
I need some code that reads the text file(info.txt) for what the user inputted and if they are both there in the same line it will print something
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONsWB.png <- here is what my files look like and here is my sign up code

```
print("Welcome to sign up Enter your details below")  
username = input("Enter Username:")        
password = input("Enter Password:")
#input text   
input_dictionary = {"one" : 1, "two" : 2}
 
#open file  
file = open("info.txt", "w")
 
#convert variable to string  
str = repr(username)  
lol = repr(password)  
file.write(str + ":" + lol +  "\n")
 
#close file  
file.close()
 
f = open('info.txt', 'r')  
if f.mode=='r':  
    contents= f.read()

print("Well done you now have a account!")
```

and so far my login page code is

```
username = input("Username:")   
password = input("Password:")
```

Comment: you don't have to convert user input to strings when you're putting it out to a file.

Comment: Note that `username` and `password` are already strings, so you can remove the conversion step. That also prevents you from overriding the built-in `str` type.

Comment: `if f.mode=='r':  `: but you just opened the file in 'r' read-mode! Don't you trust yourself?

Comment: Look into storing the Username/Password in JSON format, by doing so you could use json.load(file) with the json library then compare username/password combinations with keys of the object. [Read, Write, & Parsing JSON in python](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/json)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
username = input("Username:")   
password = input("Password:")

with open('info.txt') as f:
    # split file on newline
    users = f.read().split('\n')
    if username + ":" + password in users:
        # user logged in
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```
import time as t
f_content = open("info.txt",'r').read()
while True:
    username = input("Username:")
    password = input("Password:")
    infos = [username,password]
    for user in f_content:
        user_info = user.split(":")
        if user_info == infos:
            found = True
            print("Successfully logged in!")
            #some code

    if not found:
        print("User was not found!\nWait 20 seconds to reset")
        t.sleep(20)
```

and you should always put things like this in functions, to avoid calling external modules:

```
import time as t
f_content = open("info.txt",'r').read()
def signin():
    print("Welcome to sign up Enter your details below")  
    username = input("Enter Username:")
    password = input("Enter Password:")
    #input text   
    input_dictionary = {"one" : 1, "two" : 2}
    
    #open file  
    file = open("info.txt", "w")
    #convert variable to string  
    str = repr(username)  
    lol = repr(password)  
    file.write(str + ":" + lol +  "\n")
    #close file  
    file.close()
    f = open('info.txt', 'r')  
    if f.mode=='r':  
        contents= f.read()
    print("Well done you now have a account!")
def login(username,password):
    infos = [username,password]
    for user in f_content:
        user_info = user.split(":")
        if user_info == infos:
            found = True
            print("Successfully logged in!")
            #some code

    if not found:
        print("User was not found!\nWait 20 seconds to reset")
        t.sleep(20)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if f_content == '':
        signin()
        exit()
    while True:
        username = input("Username >> ")
        password = input("Password >> ")
        login(username,password)
```

if you though i overcomplicated things, you should do just like this:

```
username = input("Username:")   
password = input("Password:")

f = open('info.txt')
# split file on newline
users = f.read().split('\n')
if username + ":" + password in users:
    # do some code
    ...
```

Comment: there's `str.splitlines()`

Comment: with the code 

import time as t
f_content = open("info.txt",'r').read()
while True:
    username = input("Username:")
    password = input("Password:")
    infos = [username,password]
    for user in f_content:
        user_info = user.split(":")
        if user_info == infos:
            found = True
            print("Successfully logged in!")
    if not found:
        print("User was not found!\nWait 20 seconds to reset")
        t.sleep(20)

i get a error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 14, in <module>
    if not true:
NameError: name 'true' is not defined

Comment: sorry, i don't understand your problem, if there is an issue, if you could give me the code maybe in a photo, it could be helpful.